# how do you make css-transformation look 3d?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make this animation look 3d but preserve-3d is not working.... does anyone know how???

```
.initial{
width:194px;
height:250px;
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-webkit-animation: animate .8s both ease;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
to {opacity:0; -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg); }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a http://jsfiddle.net/ illustrating your problem?

Comment: You're looking for the [`perspective`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add `-webkit-perspective`

Comment: on the parent of .initial

Comment: and what should the value be?

Comment: start with 500px, then play around from there. It will change the distortion amount. i.e. how much depth in the animation there is